# How do I create a .exe file from a Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I create a .exe file from a Windows Forms application?

And I want to use it on other computers without installing Visual studio, just run it as an application.

Comment: You can only move VS an executable to another computer if the 2nd computer has same version of Net library without publishing the project and installing.  If the 2nd computer has Net then you can copy like Mhand7 suggested.

Comment: Another question full of interesting answers is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286855/how-can-i-compile-and-run-c-sharp-program-without-using-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After building the application, just go to the `bin` folder and you will find your .exe file.

Comment: I know bro but in that case you must have installed visual studio it will not work without this

Comment: no you do not, unless you are using some features from framework or other libraries that comes with Visual studio, then you should install just those. you do not need to install visual studio

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it now

Comment: Thanks I lot I installed same version of net frame work and it worked now

Comment: That's a wrong answer. What if you need 3d party dll etc ? You suggest to copy also dll ? OR you have no access to other PC where programm suppose to run???  To get exe file of your application you should publish it. If don't know how, ask me, I'll explain. It's not hard in VS.

Comment: ["Publish" implies ClickOnce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16946173/best-way-to-deploy-visual-studio-application-that-can-run-without-installing/16950135#16950135).