# Deploy ASP.net/React project with webpack directly from GIT on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs, git, jenkins

The goal is to automatically deploy a ASP.net project from GIT.
The solution (in the Visual Studio sense) consists of multiple projects, using C# and entity framework under the hood and React for the frontend. I know what to install (e.g. with npm) to get the UI transpiled (with webpack), but I am not sure what Visual Studio exactly does when you click on *Publish to folder*. I would like to do exactly that build step both for the C# backend and the React frontend using a Jenkins server.

I am also dreaming of GIT-tag-triggered builds, but that's a different question.

In summary, I have the following servers running on different (virtual) boxes:

1. GIT server
2. Jenkins server
3. Production server hosting the solution with Internet Information Services (IIS).

I know how to make (1) and (2) talk with each other, and I am able to deploy stuff from (2) to (3).  The first part of my challenge is: **What do I need to install on the Jenkins server (2) in order to build the complete solution?**

#### Related questions

- [How can I compile and run c# program without using visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286855/how-can-i-compile-and-run-c-sharp-program-without-using-visual-studio)
- Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi and Rick Anderson: [Visual Studio publish profiles for ASP.NET Core app deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Comment: I just found https://superuser.com/a/604954/754525 which looks like a good recipe. I still would love to know what the **Publish** button actually does. For the React project, it does not transpile it, I have to run `webpack -p` manually before.

Comment: You need [MSbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) for building the solution([link](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?q=build+tools) to download  Build tools without Visual studio). The simpel solution for getting this on the build server is by installing visual studio there and keep the same version as your development environment. On Jenkins you need the MSBuild plugin to further handle building the solution in the pipeline.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan: Thanks. Do you know by any chance whether the *Publish*  button does only call msbuild?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know this.